# Is this the type of question we want to be answering here?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608862/i-want-the-user-to-be-stuck-in-infinite-login-loop) today and afterward noticed that the phrase "Be nice" no longer seems to appear in the code of conduct. This seems to be a rather mean and spiteful trick to play on someone and most certainly not nice. I can see how it might be considered amusing, but it still seems over the top. I recall flagging it for moderator attention. I hope I handled this appropriately. Input?

Comment: It is a tool , can be used for good or bad. Your other option is to ask for more information, why does one want to put "bob" in a log in loop? There are valid reasons to set /bin/false as a log in shell .

Comment: I did ask why. I haven't received a constructive answer. I would understand if Bob was being fired and was expected to behave inappropriately. What disturbed me was the free-flowing answers without that information. There are also invalid reasons to set /bin/false as a login shell.

Comment: I understand. I feel similar with other types of questions, but this is sort of an advantage and disadvantage of community moderation. I am willing to bet most people at times feel "the community" makes a bad decision.

Comment: I'm actually asking "the community" for input regarding **my decision**, nothing more. "I recall flagging it for moderator attention. I hope I handled this appropriately."

Comment: I don't really think that is our responsibility to tell this person we won't answer his question. I, for one, learned something. What if it's just an April fools? Fact is, we have no way of knowing what the use case is and who knows what kind of precedent we would be setting.

Comment: @Seth. So do you feel that flagging it was incorrect, correct, or irrelevant?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245641/potentially-dangerous-and-harmful-physically-activity-related-questions-action

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102536/is-there-a-policy-on-dangerous-answers

Comment: the diffrence here is a user (not registered) is wanting to sabotage a users login - for who knows what reason? If he mentioned testing - or trying to make his security better by doing somekind of fakeout login? maybe? but just for no reason, aside from the "laughs" we all know will be at "bob's" expense, I'm not in support of this and can't see why any answers to this would have any further use than other to support trolling linux users by putting their login in a loop.

Comment: @Mateo Thank you for those insightful links. I'm sure the creator of the question got a few laughs at our expense as well. (or at least mine) ;-)

Comment: What I'm pretty sure about is that Bob will have a hard time today at work.